# Cant remove role due to attached policy

Tags: amazon-web-services

Im dynamically creating a role with an attached policy.

```
var pr = new CreateRoleRequest
{
  RoleName = roleName,
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument = asspoly.ToJson(),
};
var resp = await _iamService.CreateRoleAsync(pr);

if (resp == null || resp.HttpStatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  throw new Exception($"Could not create role: {resp.HttpStatusCode}");
}

var gresp = await _iamService.AttachRolePolicyAsync(new AttachRolePolicyRequest { RoleName = roleName, PolicyArn = GetPolicyARN(MakeRolePolicyName(agentID)) });
if (gresp == null || gresp.HttpStatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  throw new Exception($"Could not attach policy to role: {resp.HttpStatusCode}");
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I also need to remove this role.  To remove the role I need to detach the policies first.

```
var allpolys = await _iamService.ListRolePoliciesAsync(new ListRolePoliciesRequest { RoleName = roleName, MaxItems = 10 });
foreach (var poly in allpolys.PolicyNames)
{
  var polyArn = GetPolicyARN(poly);

  var dresp = await _iamService.DetachRolePolicyAsync(new DetachRolePolicyRequest { RoleName = roleName, PolicyArn = polyArn });
  if (dresp == null || dresp.HttpStatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
    throw new Exception($"Could not detach role policy: {poly}");
  }
}
```

Problem is, ListRolePolicies returns an empty list (from c# and cli) - and yet, the console shows the policy is indeed attached.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`list-role-policies`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-role-policies.html) API returns *inline* policies.  To query for *attached* policies, use the [`list-attached-role-policies`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-role-policies.html) API instead.

One could certainly argue that `list-inline-role-policies` would be a less confusing name for the former.

---

*Note on AWS Docs and IAM terminology*:

It wasn't obvious to me at first that "attached" and "managed" essentially mean the same thing.  An attached policy is either "AWS managed", or "Customer managed".  [More details here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html).

Comment: Sort of obvious now that you told me :)  Thank you!